# Default ownership and permissions for /usr/bin/apt-get

Tags: permissions, filesystem, chmod, chown

It is a home computer with only one user.

These commands have been used:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/apt-get    
chmod 4775 /usr/bin/apt-get
```

How to reverse the commands and restore defaults?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the dangerous setuid bit

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Nothing else is wrong.

---

To add a little more detail, here are the defaults:

```
$ stat -c '%a %A %U %G' /usr/bin/apt-get
755 -rwxr-xr-x root root
```

The command mentioned in the question added the setuid bit, shown as a leading `4` in octal permissions and an `s` in place of the `x` for owner in the human-readable form:

```
4755 -rwsr-xr-x
```

The setuid bit allows the user executing the program to do so with the EUID of its owner. In this case, it means the normal user running `apt-get` does so as root by default. Since `apt-get` is capable of completely destroying your system, as pointed out in comments by David Foerster and cat, giving it this permission setting (especially since the execute bit for others is set, as it is in this case, allowing literally any user to run the program) is extremely insecure.

The setuid bit, always kept to a minimum, is present by necessity on the `sudo` program

```
$ stat -c '%a %A %U %G' /usr/bin/sudo
4755 -rwsr-xr-x root root
```

To make this more secure, there is a strict policy about who may use `sudo`, configured in `/etc/sudoers`. If that file is corrupted or is not present, or if the permissions of `sudo` are wrong, `sudo` exits with errors.

Comment: `apt-get autoremove --force-yes ubuntu-minimal` for regular users. Yay!

Comment: one might add that the setuid bit is particularly more dangerous on `apt` than eg `grep`, `ls` etc because packages can contain installation triggers, arbitrary external scripts that run at various points during the `dpkg` child-process of `apt`